# Question on dielectric capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

[image]

Unfortunately this is past year practice question and I don't have answer for it.

**My attempt:**

1)Can I assume the three different layers are arranged in parallel?

2) If they are parallel, it is correct to calculate the capacitance of the device in this way:

For rubber layer: $C_1 = 4\epsilon_0\frac{100 mm x 100 mm}{0.2 mm}$

For plastic layer:$ C_2 = 9\epsilon_0\frac{100 mm x 100 mm}{0.66 mm}$

For plastic layer: $C_3 = 1.5\epsilon_0\frac{100 mm x 100 mm}{0.2 mm}$

Total capacitance = $C_1 + C_2 + C_3$

I'm not sure whether is this correct anot, can someone clarify it? Really appreciate..

Comment: This is a Standard question with lots of answers for two layers, did you search for them First?

Comment: Hi @Jasper, thanks for your comment, I actually did search for it but this time round the question asked is three layers and I wasn't confident with my answer so I would like to check with others...

Comment: Hint: you are wrong. Consider two equal layers of air composing the space between the plates. Each has capacitance of twice the whole thing (because the distance is halved). If you now add this together, your capacitance is four times larger compared to just one layer of air. Look up "capacitors in series".

Comment: @Jasper , hi sorry, can I check the set up of this question is not parallel but in series? Also why is there layer of air, I mean didn't the question says the whole setup is made up of three materials?

Comment: The "two layers of air" were just to Show that you're wrong. What makes you think that they are parallel?

Comment: @Jasper oh i see,  so my answer should be 1/C = 1/C_1 + 1/C_2 + 1/C_3?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot assume that the capacitors corresponding to the different layers are arranged in parallel. You get the total capacitance by assuming 3 parallel plate capacitors in series, each with the plate area and the thickness and dielectric constant of the corresponding layers. Furthermore, you should pay attention to the units used in this calculation, they have to be in a consistent unit system. When the free space permittivity $\epsilon_0$ is in SI units $F/m$, you have to also use $m$, not $mm$ for the dimensions of the plate capacitors.